# VEGA: How to use hover signal for data projection?

Tags: vega

I define the following signal:

```
{"name": "hovered_poll", "value": "MAAS_p1", "update": "hover ? hover.poll_id : 'MAAS_p1'"},
```

In the signal viewer, the value is correctly updated depending on my hover position. However, if I use this signal for projecting a data,

```
transform:[ 
        {"type": "project",
         "fields": [{"signal": "hovered_poll"},"cluster"],
         "as": ["selected_poll","cluster"]
        }]
```

the data is not updated. The data is only projected on 'MAAS_p1', i.e. the default value whenever no hover value is found. I can't get my head around how at the one hand the signal value is correctly updated, but at the other hand the data is not updated.

*Edit:* Here is the [link to my project](https://vega.github.io/editor/?bandwidth=36&User=Philip#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQXEACGuMxxFSKGtI7oSbEZ04ANm0w64ADyQJ7cCwxw42itXEyWyRdUNkdAC82NgRKaRAAdxpZejQANgAGTJl4GjIsNAFsmRwkWVl9MjRQTDYcDJyQOzgAM0w0ABYmpkc6hDQAJiblAo7UbsyAXxkkBjqIGki4NBBxCRWZKAlW-JqQJBcaCH3ZWKR9NFakOwg4GTUoAGsAZSWV1ABmB5pngGE2A5FKsAMQADghCTsSCYcDsADEJOMQABZCQmNhSHQAhjKGwAOTgiRAUxmIEWZHENxOqAA2qAqQgPiBkIpaJIZMQbgwPsMZgz3MyIDA2IkAPoMO7Azncj6YRQ8mRMfSyfb6HDzVawODPXouEn8taC1YAVSlCS5dh5qwAMnAUEqVWrxBrkYYXB1SVIBUzVkxwslUjALbKugJHeJVahQOrNehjEFNizLqgALQARhkyH1qHTJXJhgaua9PuZ2wYBhOMqtcoVcENjLLSLYuJDNau1Pr3qNvvjCkBpDb1vQwqQijgqobxvQItI0pAEjQ9JAcFIldWAAEoHC7KgEC27mw5wkfLIrMyz5gGANDau4Ov0Fud3uD3AWx0ZKfz6txAw7HYSQAXSnXsMCPIwJzFPx-yHZkYSrEAv0MVZZxsAB+HRUMUShoLsMUUh0VAdAAchRTRNBeKD02Iklu0bFDwPHWQoMBOxBlghi50g3CTxwS9mSw7jWNo0tVkWZYOPQPMRJ7Zk1EwFpJNRJAyHvTAkB0dNeP4zj0MwxjKG2Aw1J0QjTOIv4x16XQARwABPWxWIsdTMAgGiQLLHcxQgeU2CeJNLWHX9-xkRc6VAO8HzkJg7CgOxfiebTv3Qbd-283z-J0DDgrsMziKYRRRXEdzu0i1zVn3SUJyKgBCJLkJSryfMK-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-NJ0GTl61JbcCsGOOXxtvCa1Of19KO+jA0EAAB1v9kABqBa48kaPRejfBehor7oDdggP8DoDg0hAMQRwSZN6xxAFpBmdFpwFhznbY4+c4CFxbKLBuZd1x-SrjA2uIAoEgEbs3UmBNZAd3JPkbuukmIsRgoPV+adR7j33lPfuwlZ7R34ZA+uqxV5vxXC4Le6Ad5xCEYfER-4dCnx0BmC+kjvYpRvmUawigH7MJfuI+chj76rF-gAoBS5EZTVAQcV6ECl5SOgUDOBdj0DIOQjINBqwMxtWwaBHyeCbgARkEXUh9iwmuTzptIhCQ4m50qBAQhKxUaV3ENXGmNC6FhKhjIGGPg4b2JAUdBeUT0b7FMT4lBeM6nOPAaFcmlMfxAxuO8YJols7xLqOpSJaNi4fARikvOMEsn-WoSDdxBwyCJIoH4x+7d7HE2WqjEpOAyl0iQQ01G9RBHXiqQg+xAybjeWOYvOuej6Ft1btjPqjgLkQGOVg3pch7yLFBskkhJd0DMwobQ6ZNdZm3KePIQYqpinXR2QjIe69UbiVGZ3dhNxViBjSIaLu6KZxwHyIUX6IAcwRXkegywLQAAUxEXDESxEoygLgACUeNjqkoUeSSaVLiJ2TpToBldkWVkn9JGTFwZoxsMpLikAtIRWyDFViOVYrAJ43LA+VFUqe5qvKqSa5WdEbNlxAhaJ-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-FrPx3TozPjdCkKtEz79zMJ0s5QCNITmT6geHM+K4h7Tzjs1GRzMhgv-PyyAbjOaHN1jcwpjzSn1KlwTQ+p+ON9Q6cE8yMVMkyOWpTbczL2WPVLTyxVtYIXeNDdK6N-jZwqunC8wC8hrM-M4207Z1rKF8VjA6zg7YQIxT+go3M-wlQOErcTPsLgiBmRMTsjuUUiT7yJ3czN2rfTc7qYa48+pyFM5kehLCWKgJ-AyYO4oI76KTt6c7tqUCV2buJDu5IMkU2LgaARgAEQIXdhIhJ5jGCGZoTHEnQLbcB+l25h39Bg7kI9iVjG5v1cW2Y+eLXTu+qhxeMcTxYFr2g7q2YLgFA0Ok+gNLIA3WDcm9T64tx7gLjxOdEAvRsCxBkwlHE50BDYpw6sLrYuJsy6RymKXdxQpy+RC0doKuFJwAAArlCO9UVAGvUasieKwuhWyEhkYqW3BCkQVSuHDQ+wqwNMYmDgMm2n9D5sITI9cbcpMtlwsRnwkepJdFCjsggXorHg9PZU5e4dOrZ4qD1-48Q2x5CYeMrHTGNB-wAHkyhQAtfsQKHwrPpDJKvDmoA29+mhFDMko49G99DClQqEAThekQnxZKoBYNC+JRp1YzWZBss5TcZkXWmnLbYRJX1aKe7IoSFz8YeZp8qOTcfg-mqxLdKzH+M-0wdOTzHh8VF++NUcJHN0tP6e+quCkwsxGAmBmAfBG4y73gV7v4rjV77AL6H4YopBpCtIUzh5oCpgGZkjr595pjn4NYwQSq4EK4D6JRd5IhvCf5IJj58izDxSUit5j7NBtCehkhIQwHuhX6IHoDySKR-5uK3L5oqRJitC5406zZmrfK75QFsCV4SrsHwGMHtiWbYFKHDjTAyDtY37f5JDIHBhkh5AbbaHSqGGEqzAQDgwtxEFj4QFp4lo2o3ICT2iYDIANDvb+YMq662b9jeowF+qrABq+GqoA415wbko4bUrE6KD4aoZxAMoIpGCEZ6p0KGLBjF5FjFaiHK7iHPYGoGAkJT5l7QFV6FqdwZRwAADqehahHwyWBYLUcAjeJgLeIMCgyIjquIp8jmSku03YxBmCSK5RZ2Wu+iQIy+KUKeBoZI2Spa+Scyqk9QVgaRDOiisRks+RrYkaBSme2ersYhnmuRMahRyeJe5W-GMhchEUcBEq3eTRzePy1hyhHe0+ChEqC+IxS+7hTWGGrOm+2u4xIAu+1+tqbRYkIo4oIsp8EBPRMk-hP+EkD+a84a0wqM3ewxfxoxJOKxye5iUx-+I4OxgIex2RBxKm0a82qq8UGRQ2FxMBakacNxdedgdxLRo+TxlAneBBPe1ByhJBJgZBUSMASAI+PJw4cgNAi0o0Q+3SxhHM5+bBs+DU8+6JikwuAJq+gJKpW+AJQJMpX+0qx+iJ4wfIQ+k8VhH+fh3Be+SYp+yJ2Q-BjhTMSxnuW2O4xJIeNW+esQhexxtJJRDJtehBbJYpMx-sakeMzUfklR1Rjx6hlAnwGuCpOkEqqRtSjWTpWKUSQxspWoTUQxDp3Wl2Rs7pee3mr2PCRRshdJ1xypvxqpxKrm2JWmeMWhkOGJDZWuSo4QaAVmYIqhdZW+jZO+vRgJ7EA52uQ56Z6AdkmCXJWp18O2e2AJviQaSZc+j8DeTerJoptR0+WEaZm5zRDxwZ7elAiZmcdCnBJZORKm4y6mZIfpEq9JoR7x7ZUmnZTZjilSqB7SXwGhmp4505k5H2gJ80P56BqAgwGudB7CNRARBKnoXZ+8+gMBxBKcFQfBDwgBaZIF6yiF1pcFEwz+F5cyV5QeJJnpfUMILQQ05A94k4lZlxsBpRG53JxBiSu+r59Z75fxXxWoX5XWbAbSEFWQ-ZbZ9ZLmH5w5CQQlaB4wGY0FBw9B1WxBowZhCub+vWhFyYGFQaWFHoOF-m605BBglBqFY+6YAA7AWXQmOOtORR6ZHuMixnjI+VcSxWiYBQaouWOMuQ0mSAgbfugGKjoP-OmMMD8fqWOutlgDoAQDoOkAaJ+IqX4epAENoGQKqbXiBWEulUEJhbAbIBlVldifRcVXpSAPoFlooAAErlA0CShnZWkhXxXpgCB4zvhGB1WVCNU5nBV6FxU6Bgh4kCFyTYUOWlkvbmzPIAQPnl5Vn+kvlNVBW6FBihXhUjnr5wkYAxVODxWJUtY9U0jiWXYAnsavIDDgXyUJnTHwDPZRWrCUoMq5WYDlWhX8prFlX5VwBMoEA-RzmxnMggjZAjldIMGA25lwHCqaUoXaXoWyAFVXmMkgXnVvJ2GOk8HjWwHFFPk1msXaUggCBQXE14xI0nmrBJUz7JmgCLH3E4EWUBXLU6EhVhURViWSo6GmF7UJV4xg0qVMHbhQ1IV-pZZw0pAI0VWAymV6kc3Sp1qUohWNpnxc1Ygq06BipMo6AABUO0lAmQnQpN2FEN6AjE95aeqMw09FrCnl3lWJ-gbc8uiu-QqYalpMvBzIKs10hRgZPcv2cIURMlpuHSotMgltkYAAGkzdKizWCCOWHbIAAJpR3RUIWDWDBnmk10D1kvAuTHCPAIRuW0JZ0wGvGYwUEy24HynBowhwjHWVXV6gE0A+rFal34zl1UGV3nm6pTBAA), the graphics on the right should change depending on the hover position which determines the nearest black point (i.e. the poll for which the statistics are calculated for)

Comment: Hi, this is due to the fact that your data proprety isnt responsive to signal update events inside a transform. Can you provide a share of your work on the online editor and explain the purpose of your need ?
Also, data update works with triggers https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/triggers/

Comment: thanks for your comment, I added the link above and explained the purpose. I will see if triggers can serve my purpose.

Comment: So I was able to do it without using the "project" method by only referring to the "filter" method where signal values can be directly used.